# JAX-RS: Retrieving an attribute from a post() Response

Tags: java, neo4j, xml-parsing, jax-rs

I need to retrieve an attribute from a `Response` object which is returned from a `post()` invocation: in particular, I'm using Neo4J and after posting a node I would like to retrieve its Id, which is an attribute in the returned XML code. My current post looks like this:

```
Response res = target.path("resource/node").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
              .post(Entity.entity(node, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
```

Then I perform a check on the returned HTTP status and I would also need the node Id, which is returned in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<node xmlns="http://www.namespace.org/Neo4J" id="140">
 ... node properties ...
</node>
```

I tried to cast `res.getEntity()` to a `Document` but it causes the following:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector$2 cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Document
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be aware that saving the neo4j-assigned id for nodes is bad practice, as when nodes are deleted, those ids become available to reuse for new nodes, so the ids you are saving may become stale and not refer to the nodes they referred to originally. Also, I do not know if there are guarantees about ids remaining the same for nodes between backups and restores. In any case internal ids are meant for internal neo4j usage only, and you should use your own custom ID fields instead.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Thank you for the advice, I was thinking about saving them in order to be able to compose easily the required URL when I'll manage them or create relationships, that will be `/Neo4JXML/rest/resource/node/<node_id>` and `/Neo4JXML/rest/resource/node/<node_id>/relationship` respectively. I even tried to impose a node ID during the `post()` by sending its attribute after the namespace, but in the returned `Response` the specified Id wasn't the one I imposed. So how could I used custom IDs? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JAXB to map POST body XML data to java object:

```
Payload entity = res.getEntity(Payload.class);
String id = payload.id;
```

where Payload you can define to reflect your XML structure:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;


@XmlRootElement(name="node")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Payload {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    String id; // for example
}
```